# pdftotext - Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap

Tags: pdf, xpdf

I am running pdftotext on a bunch of pdfs, and some of them throw this error:

```
Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
```

I took a look at the outfiles, and they seem to look ok, so I'm not sure if it's a significant error, but I am concerned. Does anyone know what this error is, what causes it, and how much damage there is because of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be having trouble converting a character to a unicode equivalent. I'm guessing it will cause little or no damage, and it's probably caused by an ASCII only encoded PDF.